# Change state of element declared in JSX

Tags: react-native

I'm implementing the react native swiper (https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) in a project

```
class MainSwiper extends React.Component {
  _onMomentumScrollEnd() {
    // Edit some state of the SomeView here...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onMomentumScrollEnd}>
        <View>
          <SomeView />
        </View>
        // More views here...
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('some_app', () => MainSwiper);
```

And I want the method `_onMomentumScrollEnd()` to change some state of the `SomeView` declared in the JSX.

Suppose `SomeView` is defined as:

```
class SomeView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {somestate = 'Hi!'};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.state.somestate}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

I realize I might be approaching this issue in the wrong way, but I don't know how it's done. How can `somestate` be changed from `_onMomentumScrollEnd()` (or any other `MainSwiper` method) and get the `SomeView` to re-render, i.e. how do I access the `SomeView`element from within a `MainSwiper` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass state to the `SomeView` component by its props. So you could do

```
class MainSwiper extends React.Component {
  _onMomentumScrollEnd() {
    this.setState({somestate: A String})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        onMomentumScrollEnd={this._onMomentumScrollEnd}>
        <View>
          <SomeView somestate={this.state.somestate} />
        </View>
        // More views here...
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('some_app', () => MainSwiper);
```

And then in SomeView

```
class SomeView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.somestate}</Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Notice how the SomeView component became a stateless component by not keeping its own state. It's not mandatory but it's [a good practice](https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc#.tj1mnq6o4).